# Generate API calls dynamically

Tags: open-source, api, automation

I have a requirement that keep changing (like, once a week).
We have several rules : A, B, C, D, E.
Each of the rules basically calls API from our internal data or external party.
Each rules might have different request / response.
So we build an API X with input parameters are all possible input for all rules.
This API X, have a certain logic to execute rules based on product.
Based on certain products (say Smartphone, or Macbook), we need to build logic, in which some of the rules must be executed, in particular order.

So the API X backend have this kind of algoritm:

```
if (product = 'smartphone') then
  response_A = call API_A(name, birth_date)
  if not response_A.is_valid_birth_date()
    return response_X_false

  response_B = call_API_B(name, payment_method)
  if not response_A.is_valid_payment_method()
    return response_X_false

  return response_X_smartphone

else if (product = 'macbook') then
  response_A = call API_A(name, birth_date)
  if not response_A.is_valid_birth_date()
    return response_X_false

  response_D = call API_D(email, phone)
  if not response_D.is_valid_email()
    return response_X_false

  response_B = call_API_B(name, payment_method)
  if not response_A.is_valid_payment_method()
    return response_X_false

  return response_X_macbook

else if (some other product) then
  do a sequence calling
```

We build this API X into our Java code, which quickly became uncontrollable and error-prone

1. Every time there is new product, we have to re-code which API to calls, and the calling sequence
2. On example above, macbook calls A-D-B. Risk team might change this calls into B-E-A at certain times.

So we having difficulties to keep up with changes on API X.
I wonder if there's any tools to generate this kind of logic instead of write codes.
Basically this is a repetitive task.

At first, I'm thinking about BRM engine like drools or OpenL, but after a research, such BRM engine is basically comparing field(s) to get output. While in our case, we calls API, and the sequence of calling is matter.

Any reccomendation?

Thank you

Comment: "`I have a requirement that keep changing (like, once a week)`" . ***There's*** your problem. Stop coding! Right now!!